# Jasper Report: Creación de una tabla con creación dinámica de columnas según los datos de una api

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jaspersoft

Estoy creando un informe con Jasper Reports 6.16 que se ejecutará en una aplicación empresarial. Desde la api de la app puedo obtener una lista de hashmaps. A continuación muestro un ejemplo de lista:

```
[{oficio=arquitecto,genero=hombre,categoria=junior,nacion=España},
{oficio=arquitecto,genero=hombre,categoria=junior,nacion=Francia},
{oficio=arquitecto,genero=hombre,categoria=junior,nacion=Marruecos},
{oficio=arquitecto,genero=mujer,categoria=Senior,nacion=España},
{oficio=arquitecto,genero=mujer,categoria=Senior,nacion=Francia},
{oficio=arquitecto,genero=mujer,categoria=Senior Plus,nacion=Argelia},
{oficio=arquitecto,genero=mujer,categoria=Senior,nacion=Reimo Unido},
{oficio=diseñador,genero=hombre,categoria=Senior,nacion=Estados Unidos},
{oficio=diseñador,genero=mujer,categoria=Senior Plus,nacion=Marruecos}]
```

La tabla que tengo que hacer es la siguiente:

| Oficio | Género | Categoría | Total | España | Francia | Marruecos | Argelia | Reino Unido | Estados Unidos |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| arquitecto | hombre | junior | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| arquitecto | mujer | Senior | 3 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| arquitecto | mujer | Senior Plus | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| diseñador | hombre | Senior | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| diseñador | mujer | Senior Plus | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Como se puede observar, los registros que se deben mostrar en la tabla contienen el número de trabajadores que hay en cada nación agrupados por oficio, genero y categoría. Las columnas de cada nación deben aparecer solo si aparecen en el mensaje de respuesta de la API, pero no se puede saber de antemano que países pueden ser devueltos por dicha consulta.

El objetivo es obtener un archivo `.jasper` que al subirlo a la aplicación, pueda generar el PDF desde la misma aplicación.

Si alguien se ha encontrado con este reto o conoce una posible solución, agradeceré toda aportación.

Comment: Consulta lo que es un `pivot` y unos cuantos `group by` en el sql te pueden generar el reporte que necesitas, posteriormente la `data` la envias a el `.jasper` para que te genere el repote.

Comment: Hola gracias por el comentario, pero precisamente el problema que tengo es que la única manera que tengo de interactuar con la base de datos es a través de una API en Java. La idea es tomar los datos desde el Query dialog editor con Beanshell, para posteriormente subir el `.jasper` a la aplicación (que no controlo yo) que contiene una lógica para ejecutarlo y exportar un PDF

Comment: Que versión de java estas usando donde va  ser ejecutado??

Comment: La versión es Java 11